# PHP HTTP POST fails when cURL data > 1024

Tags: php, http, post, curl

**Note: solution at the end**

If I attempt to do a HTTP POST of over 1024 characters, it fails. Why? Here is a minimal example:

recipient.php:

```
<?php
if (strlen(file_get_contents('php://input')) > 1000
    || strlen($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) > 1000) {
 echo "This was a triumph.";
}
?>
```

sender.php:

```
<?php
function try_to_post($char_count) {
 $url = 'http://gpx3quaa.joyent.us/test/recipient.php';
 $post_data = str_repeat('x', $char_count);
 $c = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($c,
                    array(  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 999,
                            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data
                    )
 );
 $result = curl_exec($c);
 echo "{$result}\n";
 curl_close($c);
}

for ($i=1020;$i<1030;$i++) {
 echo "Trying {$i} - ";
 try_to_post($i);
}
?>
```

output:

```
Trying 1020 - This was a triumph.
Trying 1021 - This was a triumph.
Trying 1022 - This was a triumph.
Trying 1023 - This was a triumph.
Trying 1024 - This was a triumph.
Trying 1025 - 
Trying 1026 - 
Trying 1027 - 
Trying 1028 - 
Trying 1029 -
```

configuration:

```
PHP Version 5.2.6
libcurl/7.18.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.8
lighttpd-1.4.19
```

**Solution**

Add the following option for cURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
```

The reason seems to be that any POST over 1024 character causes the "Expect: 100-continue" HTTP header to be sent, and Lighttpd 1.4.* does not support it. I found a ticket for it: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/show/1017

They say it works in 1.5.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can convince PHP's curl backend to stop doing the 100-continue-thing by setting an explicit request header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

This way you can post a request however long you would ever want and curl will not do the dual phase post.

I've [blogged about this](http://www.gnegg.ch/2007/02/the-return-of-except-100-continue/) nearly two years ago.

Comment: Thank you! Solved it for me. But in my case, I'm using the PHP PECL HttpRequest module through nginx. The equatable solution is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.addheaders.php#86798

Answer (score 3):

### First thoughts...

The manual page for [curl_setopt](http://php.net/curl_setopt) says of  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

> "The full data to post in a HTTP "POST"
>   operation. To post a file, prepend a
>   filename with @ and use the full path.
>   This can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like
>   'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an
>   array with the field name as key and
>   field data as value."

Could it be that your value is being treated as if it were urlencoded, and thus looks like a big long name with no value. Something somewhere is deciding to truncate that name.

Maybe you could alter it to something like

```
$post_data = "data=".str_repeat('x', $char_count);
```

Turns out this was too easy, and the problem was a little deeper. So, how to debug?

### Find out exactly what CURL sends to the server

Another debugging tactic might be to formulate a curl command line which achieves the same thing, and have it output the HTTP request details as it makes them.

### Testing the server by hand

You can eliminate the server from the equation by perform a request by hand, e.g. telnetting to port 80 on your server and sending it a request >1024 chars

```
POST /test/recipient.php HTTP/1.0
Host: gpx3quaa.joyent.us
Content-Length:1028

xxxxx(I put 1028 chars here, no point copying them all here!)
```

I got this response

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 19
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2009 21:35:16 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.19

This was a triumph.Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So at least you now know it's all on the client side, possible some CURL option or configuration setting somewhere :(

### Final Answer!

The problem intrigued me so I dug deeper

If you use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>true`, you'll see that  CURL sends an extra header on the bigger posts:`Expect: 100-Continue`. Your lighttpd server doesn't like this, it would seem.

You can stop CURL from doing this by forcing it to use HTTP/1.0 with `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION=>CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0` in your curl_setopt options array.

Comment: Tried it, still fails. Although now it of course fails 5 characters earlier.

Comment: I see we arrived at the same conclusion. It was a fun puzzle :)

Comment: Well, I arrived at my own answer first using your suggestion to debug using command-line and googling for it, then checked back here and noticed that pilif had posted the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a IIS server, using SSL v3.

I kept getting the following cURL error when CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS was longer than 1024 :

```
52 - SSL read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number, errno 0
```

Adding CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER : "Expect:" solved the problem for me.

Thank you so much for this thread!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Suhosin patch enabled. By default, it cuts off POST data after certain number of indexes. You can bypass it in Suhosin config tho.